# Python AST: several semantics unclear, e.g. expr_context

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Is there any more than the [`ast` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html) about the `ast` module?

Esp., I am wondering what `expr_context` (and all its possible values) exactly means.

Also, what is the difference between `Assign` and `AugAssign`?

Also, it is possible to reference to a real Python object instead of its name when doing an assignment to a local variable? I am building an AST myself and I have some Python objects which I want to access to in the AST. The alternative would be to introduce some dummy temp var name for them and add that dummy var name to the `globals()` scope for the later compiled function but that seems somewhat bad (slow and hacky) to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'll try to answer it myself.

After some more testing and guessing:

`expr_context` is where the `Name` is defined, e.g. if it is in an assignment on the left side (`Store`, `AugStore`), right side (`Load`, `AugLoad`), in a `del` (`Del`) or in an argument list like from `FunctionDef` or `Lambda` (`Param`).

`AugAssign` is like `a = a <op> b`. `Assign` is just a simple `a = b`.

I haven't found a way to reference to a real Python object and it seems like there is none.

Comment: `AugLoad` and `AugStore` aren't actually used in ASTs, and `Param` has been unused since 3.0. All 3 are gone in 3.9; it's just Load, Store, and Del now.

Answer (score 2):

You can 'smuggle' a real Python object into the AST by use of Str(s=) or Num(n=).  For example, the following passes a function object directly by replacing a string.

```
import ast

data = '''
x = '1234'
x()
'''
def testfunc():
    print "inside test function"
tree = compile(data, '<string>', 'exec', ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST)

class ModVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit(self, node):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Str):
            node.s = testfunc
        self.generic_visit(node)

ModVisitor().visit(tree)

code = compile(tree, '<string>', 'exec')
exec code # prints "inside test function"
```

Note: I checked this in Python 2.7. I'm not sure whether there is a guarantee that this will hold true for earlier or later versions.