# Understanding ctx in Python's ast

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree, python-internals

What is the `ctx` argument in the Python AST representation? For example:

```
>>> print(ast.dump(ast.parse('-a')))
Module(body=[Expr(value=UnaryOp(op=USub(), operand=Name(id='a', ctx=Load())))])
```

In other words, what does `ctx=Load()` mean or do? The only information I'm able to see from the docs is that the ctx may be one of:

```
expr_context = Load | Store | Del | AugLoad | AugStore | Param
```

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ast.html. Could someone explain the various `expr_context` and what those do? I suppose lhs and rhs are the store/load:

```
>>> print(ast.dump(ast.parse('b=-a')))
Module(body=[Assign(targets=[Name(id='b', ctx=Store())], value=UnaryOp(op=USub(), operand=Name(id='a', ctx=Load())))])
```

But beyond that, what are all the other options?

---

**Update:** Also, yes there is another question similar to this, [Python AST: several semantics unclear, e.g. expr_context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679171), but the accepted answer starts with `"After some more testing and guessing:..."` and it pretty light (to say the least) on details. I'm hoping that someone who actually understands the `ast` module a bit more can provide a more thorough answer.

Comment: @MikeScotty that is pretty light -- even the answerer says he doesn't know much and it's a lot of guess-and-check. Hopefully we can find something a bit more useful for others? Did you read the accepted answer?

Comment: Note that contexts are different on different Python versions. The Python 3.9 docs only list Load, Store, and Del.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica oh wow, that's much more intuitive and easier to understand with just the three...

Comment: The 3.9 docs also have [actual documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.Load) for Load, Store, and Del.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica thanks! 3.9 has fantastic documentation for it too, before then it's quite bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An expression in `Load` context is having its value computed. `Store` means an expression is being assigned to (including in ways like being used as a `with` or `for` target), and `Del` means that an expression is being deleted (with `del`). This is described in the [Python 3.9 `ast` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.Load), which are much better than the 3.7 docs.

`Param`, `AugLoad`, and `AugStore` can be safely ignored. As of Python 3.7, they never appear in an actual AST, and as of 3.9, they are completely gone, even at the implementation level. In 3.7, `AugLoad` and `AugStore` sometimes appeared in [temporary objects](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.9/Python/compile.c#L4581-L4588) created internally by the compiler, but never in an actual AST. As far as I can tell, `Param` hasn't been used ever since the introduction of function annotations forced a redesign of the AST representation for function parameters in Python 3.0.

Comment: Param used to be used in python2.x:  ```$ astpretty /dev/stdin <<< 'def f(x): pass' | grep Name
                args=[Name(lineno=1, col_offset=6, id='x', ctx=Param())],
```

Comment: @AnthonySottile: Looks like the difference is because function annotations forced a change in the AST representation for function parameters back in 3.0. I've expanded the answer a bit.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica question: when you say `...sometimes appeared in temporary objects created internally by the compiler` -- what is the "compiler" in this case? Do you mean the https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/18ce7f1d0a3d65f34f25c5964da588743a1bfe3c/Python/Python-ast.c and related files?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249: I'm talking about the bytecode compiler, responsible for converting an AST to Python bytecode.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I see: thanks for the clarification. Do know what file(s) that's in in the python repository by change?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249: [The one I linked.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.9/Python/compile.c#L4581-L4588)